Issue Importing Deliminated Text File from Google Sheets in QGIS3
I'm using QGIS3 and I'm trying to import a deliminated text layer into QGIS from a google sheet document. Whenever I import the file into QGIS it comes with an error icon stating that the layer is unavailable. I think it might be something to do with the co-ordinates i'm using.

r/QGIS - Issue Importing Deliminated Text File from Google Sheets in QGIS3
Below is an example of the X and Y columns (I believe it's British National Grid). I tried removing the commas by using the Find and Replace feature and then also formatted the number so it showed as plain text.

I've also tried copying and pasting the data into a new google sheets document and trying to import that into QGIS.
However, when I take these steps, it still shows up as an unavailable layer and i'm not sure why. Is anyone able to give some advice on what's going on here?
Thank you :)
I tried removing the commas by using the Find and Replace feature and then also formatted the number so it showed as plain text.
I've also tried copying and pasting the data into a new google sheets document and trying to import that into QGIS.
